What do outer forms of simple algebraic groups of type $^{2}D_n$ look like?
The root system $D_n$ has a nontrivial automorphism of order 2 for n at least 4, which means $SO_{2n}$ should have outer forms. But is there a nice algebraic way to describe them as different from the inner forms?
For example for $A_n$ we get that inner forms come from $SL_m(D)$ where D is a division algebra with involution of first kind and orthogonal type, while the type $^2 A_n$ groups are $SU_m(D)$ where D is a division algebra over a quadratic extension over the base field and it has an involution of second kind. Is there a good way to describe the outer forms of $D_n$ this way?

Note that your description of inner forms in the $A_n$ case is not correct: you don't need any involution on $D$, any division algebra works. It is only for the outer forms that you need some unitary involution. The inner forms correspond to the case where the quadratic extension is split, meaning that it is isomorphic to $K\times K$.

In general a group of type $D_n$ will correspond to some algebra with orthogonal involution $(A,\sigma)$ of degree $2n$. I assume that the characteristic of the base field is not $2$, otherwise you need to replace "orthogonal involution" with so-called "quadratic pairs", as defined in the Book of Involutions, which is the non-split version of replacing bilinear forms with quadratic forms, which are not the same in characteristic 2.
If you're interested in groups like $SO_{2n}$, they correspond to $SO(A,\sigma)$, which is the group of elements $a\in A$ which satisfy
$$ a\sigma(a) = 1_A$$
and
$$Nrd_A(a) = 1$$
where $Nrd_A: A\to K$ is the reduced norm of $A$ (the non-split equivalent of the discriminant).
To an algebra with orthogonal involution you can associate its (signed) discriminant, which generalizes the discriminant of a quadratic form. Then your algebraic group is an inner form (of a split group) if and only if the discriminant is trivial.
Precisely, you can define the (even) Clifford algebra $C(A,\sigma)$, and its center is a quadratic étale extension of the base field, which corresponds to the square class of the discriminant. The algebraic groups associated to $(A,\sigma)$ are inner forms if and only if this center is actually split, ie isomorphic to $K\times K$, in which case $C(A,\sigma)\simeq C^+\times C^-$ for two components which are central simple algebras over $K$. In some sense (the key word is "Tits algebras") each of these components is associated to one of the two twin vertices in the Dynkin diagram of type $D_n$, and the non-trivial automorphism of the diagram permutes them.

How do you know that a form is inner if and only if the discriminant is trivial? And how do you define the discriminant of an involution on a central simple algebra? Do you have sources?

Hey just following up in case you didn't see this
